# Crop an image (select a region) in Sencha Touch 2? Just like Jcrop

Tags: sencha-touch-2, jcrop

This does exactly what I need and works in mobile Safari: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html

I need to do this in Sencha Touch 2

I could roll my own from scratch or based on Jcrop but my project's budget probably doesn't support that amount of time. So, I guess the fastest route is to add jQuery to the ST2 project and hack in the use of the plugin into one of the ST2 views.

So my question is, how should I load jQuery – right now I've got ST2 loading my JS files on demand (they're not in the  of index.html).

OR

Can you point me to a ST2 alternative to Jcrop?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like I could use an ajax script in ST2 to load then eval the jQuery scripts. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?189567-What-would-be-the-best-way-to-include-3rd-party-components-into-a-Sencha-Touch-App&p=854257#post854257

Answer (score 0):

You can have the frameworks you need for your development. Only JS files correctly directing each framework.

I currently am using Sencha Touch 2 and JQuery mobile in my financial business development.

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Can you point me to a ST2 alternative to Jcrop?**

There is no ST2 alternative at the moment as far as I know. I'm currently working on one but it could take weeks before it's done.

**How should I load jQuery**

I don't think there is a way to only load the parts of jQuery you need so just add something like this add the end of your index.html file :

Hope this helps

Comment: Did you ever build your own solution?